# Change the font used for Times-Roman (fontconfig)

Tags: fonts, evince

(I'm having a hard time figuring this one out and my google-fu is not helping.)

For a long time, my evince has used a strange Times-Roman font (with mis-aligned glyphs and weird kerning). It should instead be replaced by times new roman. I am not very familiar with fontconfig, but this see some output:

```
$ fc-match "Times New Roman"
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"

$ fc-list : file | grep -iP "msttcorefonts/times"
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/times.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/Times_New_Roman.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesi.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbd.ttf: 
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/timesbi.ttf:
```

It seems to me that Times-Roman should use the existing times new roman to render, but that instead it is using DejaVu. I've tried changing the file `.fonts.config` but I still can't change that output.

**My question:** What should I put into the `.fonts.config` file to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you install Windows fonts?

Comment: Yes I did, using `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: Do you still have this problem?